# ubuntu/linux hardrive clone with dd issue with partitions and allocated side

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, dd, gparted

I have a 500gb hardrive (sda) with 2 allocated partition (sda1 and sda2 which is the linux swap) (see image).

I want to copy the data of 500gb hardrive to a 2tb hardrive named sdb. So I did

```
dd if=/dev/sda of/dev/sdb
```

The data are copied properly to sdb but the big problem is that I get a big unallocated space at the end of sdb. I tried to use gparted afterwards to make sdb1 bigger but i cannot make it biger because sdb2 [the swap] is on the right side.

So my question is how to copy the sda2 small swap as is on my new hardrive and copy the sda1 data but making full usage of the new hardrive (i.e. approx full 2tb insetad of the 450.07gb].

PS: I do not mind restarting everything and using other methods (does not need to be dd or gparted) but what is important is that i end up with a sdb1 of approx 2tb and that tiny sdb2 swap

[image]

edit: thanks to @mjb2kmn now it works
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a viable method to clone to a larger disk. Copy the bytes over exactly then recreate the partition table.

Since the extended partition only has swap in it, you can delete it, resize sda1 (leaving space for swap), then recreate the extended partition and the logical swap partition.

Comment: I did it but  now I see a no such partition entering in rescure mode > grub rescure ask me to enter some command. What shall I do?

Comment: ah is ok i used method 1 of that video https://youtu.be/OJTGpvZO8Oc

Comment: Interesting. I've done this type of thing manually with fdisk and don't think it's ever caused an issue with grub. Glad you got it handled though!